# I don't quite understand how a MySql connection looks like

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, forms

Today I have been sitting at my computer trying out how you would go about connecting and using a MySql database. I have a lot of questions but i will try to keep to a few.

1. When i initialize a connection to my server with the statement `sqlConnection.Open();`
   Is this connection now open and ready to use until i tell the server otherwise?
2. The `Close()` statement does not seem to close the connection, if i watch my Server status i can see that the connection is still there after i send it.
3. Say i want to retrieve data from my database, i first do my function `setupConnection();`
   This fuuction sends `Open()` and then return true or false. Then i would likely have a function that retrieves data for display and calculations etc. When i call this function would i need to open the connection again?

To sum it up a little, is the connection only open when the program is in the same scope as the `Open();` function?

And also what can i do to not have to declare this in every function:

MySqlConnection sqlConnection;
sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection();

Here is some code ive been doing today:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// InitConnection outputs the connectionstring
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Adress">Server adress</param>
    /// <param name="Port">Server port</param>
    /// <param name="Uid">Username</param>
    /// <param name="Pwd">Password</param>
    /// <param name="Database">Database</param>
    /// <returns>the connectionstring</returns>
    public string initConnection(string Adress, string Port, 
         string Uid, string Pwd, string Database)
    {
        return "server=" + Adress + ";port=" + Port + ";uid=" + Uid + ";" +
            "pwd=" + Pwd + ";database=" + Database + ";";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// setuupConnection will setup an active connection to the database 
    /// specified in initConnection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ConnectionString">The return value of 
    /// initConnection</param>
    /// <returns>True or False</returns>
    public bool setupConnection(string ConnectionString)
    {
        MySqlConnection sqlConnection;
        sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection();
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;            
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
        return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            { 
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.");
                    break;
                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalide username/password.");
                    break;
            }
        return false;
        } 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// closeConnection will terminate the database connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True or False</returns>
    public bool closeConnection()
    {
        MySqlConnection sqlConnection;
        sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection();
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Dispose();
        return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return false;
        }  
    }
```

Comment: If I might make a suggestion: It seems like you're trying to learn about databases in general correct? If so I would highly recommend you start with MSSQL. There are far more resources about how to connect a .Net app to an MSSQL database so you'll have a much easier time diagnosing issues. Once you're comfortable with that *then* I would recommend experimenting with MySql. One step at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Your are setting up your connections within the scope of your setup and close functions. You setup your connection, open it, then your function ends and the connection goes out of scope. In your close function, you are are defining a connection only to dispose of it, which makes no sense. Setup your connection, open it, **use it**, then close it.

It would appear that you should study and understand variable scoping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://connectionstring.com very useful website:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

> Standard
>
> `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`
>
> Specifying TCP port
>
> ```
>  Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
> ```
>
> The port 3306 is the default MySql port. The value is ignored if Unix
>   socket is used.
>
> Multiple servers Use this to connect to a server in a replicated
>   server configuration without concern on which server to use.
>
> ```
>  Server=serverAddress1, serverAddress2, serverAddress3;Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
> ```
>
> Using encryption (old) This one activates SSL encryption for all data
>   sent between the client and server. The server must have a certificate
>   installed.
>
> ```
>   Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;Encrypt=true;
> ```
>
> This option is available for Connector/NET version 5.0.3 through
>   6.2.1. From 6.2.1 use the SslMode option instead.
>
> Using encryption (new) Use SSL if the server supports it, but allow
>   connection in all cases
>
> ```
>   Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
> ```
>
> SslMode=Preferred; This option is available from Connector/NET version
>   6.2.1
>
> Force encryption Always use SSL. Deny connection if server does not
>   support SSL.
>
> ```
>   Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
> ```
>
> SslMode=Required; This option is available from Connector/NET version
>   6.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand fully the question. You tried to connect to MySQL, and you managed to do it; but then stopped. Why?

Actually, everything is simple, and there are many-many examples in the internet.

Do you want to retrieve data from the MySQL table? One variant is to use IDataReader:

- create a MySqlCommand
- run ExecureReader method
- get IDataReader instance
- read records, one-by-one.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes i managed to connect to my server, however i didnt understand the concept fully, so i connected with one function, saw it in my server status window. Then ii left the function that i connected with thinking that i would be connected until i sent a disconnect/close. But as phoenixreborn said i have too connect, do my dirty work and close in the same scope.

My final product should only have the read function. I still have to learn in what manner i can read data, do my calculations and print them to my form as well as updating the data almost realtime.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, if you call Open() and don't get exception then you are ready to use. You should generate a SQL and send it to the server using command object.
2. in your "closeconnection" method you just create a new connection object and right after that you dispose it. you don't even open that connection.
3. you need to declare your connection object inside class, not in the method. Doing this allows you to use only one connection object and allows your code to run. Your current code not working because you use different connection objects in each method.

However, database connections are expensive and if you don't use connection very often then you should probably open connection-do your job with the database-close it. Opening database connections at the beginning and keeping connection open till the end of your application is not a good practice.

And I think, as @PhoenixReborn stated, you should study variable scopes.